# How can define linked server to be accessible from every username?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, linked-server

I have a view in sql server 2008 that selects from a linked server.

I am able to select from the view only if I open SSMS `as administrator` .

If I do not open SSMS as admin and try to select from the view, I get the error `unspecified error`

Here's my linked server:

```
use master
go
EXEC sp_AddLinkedServer @server     = 'SectionA', 
                        @srvproduct = '',
                        @provider   = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                        @datasrc    = 'C:\SectionAReport\', 
                        @provstr    = 'Text'
```

How can I allow ALL USERS to select from this view?

Comment: Did you try giving guest or user read access to that file?

Comment: This look like a permission or login (user) issue? please check grant select permisson on view? does use's loging have access using link server?

Comment: @Blam the user has access to the file. i can open that file from the C drive, but cannot run the view if i do not open as admin

Comment: @Hiten004 yes, the user has access only if open as admin on that specific user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "[sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189811.aspx)" you should be able to set the remote permissions.

Specifically, try this

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = 'SectionA'
     , @useself = 'FALSE'
     , @locallogin = NULL -- all local users
     , @rmtuser = 'whatevername'
     , @rmtpassword = 'whateverpassword'
```